# On Mac OSX using FileVault 2, are all user's files unencrypted if the current user has rights to login from cold boot up?

Tags: encryption

I am taking my Macbook into an Authorized Service Provider to run diagnostics on battery performance and my data is encrypted using FileVault 2. I am assuming the technician(s) will want the ability to login.

If I create a user account for them that will be enabled to decrypt the drive, how easy is it at that point to access data from another user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of the purpose of full disk encryption (FDE). It's job is to protect from an *offline* attack, where the disk is removed and connected to another computer.

If your computer is turned on, then FDE is no longer doing anything to protect your disk. At this point, you are being protected by the Mac's operating system's access controls, not FileVault.

Those aren't bad, although of course if the technical account needs admin rights to run the diagnostic tool...

Finally, as ever, there is immutable law #3 to consider: "[If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx)"

You'll have to evaluate your threat model. What are the risks? What do you fear the technician might do, and what would that cost you? Based on this you can work out what will make the risk acceptable. For example:

If the risk is low, then your plan to create a separate account should be fine.

If your risk is high, then a safer approach is to wipe the hard drive before bringing it in, then restoring your sensitive data afterwards.

If your risk is very high, then you'll just have to not get your machine serviced.